# check external website registration key

Tags: php, parsing

I would like to create simple serial key checker but it needs to be checked on other domain

At `www.my_site_1.com`

Form code

```
<form action="install.php" method="post">
Serial : <input type="text" name="serial" id="serial">
<input type="submit" value="Install">
</form>
```

I think i need to use parsing to get the results from `check.php` so any informations how to do it. ~ thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set the POST/GET URL in the action property and pass the serial directly to check.php. In your case, you want to send a GET variable I assume.

install.php shold look like:

```
<form action="http://my_site_2.com/check.php" method="GET">
Serial : <input type="text" name="serial" id="serial">
<input type="submit" value="Install">
</form>
```